# Changing details on a submitted Iceland visa application

Tags: schengen-visas, iceland

I submitted my Iceland visa application online on applyvisa.um.dk since Denmark handles visa applications to Iceland. The application cannot be edited now and I have also paid the visa fees and scheduled an appointment with VFS  in Toronto.

However, I wish to change the hotel that I indicated on the visa form since am thinking of basing my stay in Reykjavik. How do I go about it? I thought of a few options:

1. Base my itinerary around the hotel I booked (which is in NW Iceland) and submit it for visa purposes.
2. Go ahead and include the new hotel booking and just let VFS know at my appointment that I decided to change my itinerary a bit.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you could show up with both itineraries printed out, and tell the interviewer you'd like to base in Reykjavik instead of the hotel in the NW if that would be acceptable.